# How does Eclipse/IDEA/etc. debugger obtain the information about local variable values and watch expression values?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea

I always thought that varibales are mapped to stack locations once your Java source is compiled; additionally, they may include the info about the variable names and their scope in classfiles, but that's optional AFAIK.

The question is - how do my Eclipse/IDEA IDEs allow me to set a watch expression containing the local variable name? To me, it's hard to understand :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All those IDE base their debug services on top of the [JavaTM Platform Debugger Architecture (JPDA)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/index.html).
More precisely, they are all using the [**Java Virtual Machine Tool Interface (JVM TI)**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/index.html), which replaced from JDK5 the experimental JVMPI (Java Virtual Machine Profiling Interface).

That JVMTI includes a [Watched Field function](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#fieldWatch) and a [SetFieldModificationWatch function](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#SetFieldModificationWatch).

But that **doesn't include local variable**: there is actually an RFE opened since quite some time now: [bug 4228507](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=d2dbbc5876f2bffffffffc8bdeaf7e6d5180?bug_id=4228507).
So in the case of local variable, chances are some kind of [BCI](http://docs.hp.com/en/JAVAPERFTUNE/bytecode.pdf) is used (**Byte Code Instrumentation**) (like the [TPTP Eclipse module does](http://wiki.eclipse.org/TPTP-AG-20080205)).

Comment: Local vars are fields? Really?

Comment: @Bubba88: I agree, that doesn't include local vars. I suppose custom BCI agents are associated with the debug session to wrap those local vars in method call, to be able to watch them. I have completed my answer with some references, but nothing yet definitive.